# C# - Assign values to controls thought loop

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, controls

I have controls that are named in numeric sequence. 
I'd like to assign values those controls using loop.
The code below is the way i'm currently using.

```
txtSalesInvoiceForm_Qty1.Text = (salesInvoice.ItemQty1 == 0) ? string.Empty : salesInvoice.ItemQty1.ToString();
txtSalesInvoiceForm_Qty2.Text = (salesInvoice.ItemQty2 == 0) ? string.Empty : salesInvoice.ItemQty2.ToString();
txtSalesInvoiceForm_Qty3.Text = (salesInvoice.ItemQty3 == 0) ? string.Empty : salesInvoice.ItemQty3.ToString();
txtSalesInvoiceForm_Qty4.Text = (salesInvoice.ItemQty4 == 0) ? string.Empty : salesInvoice.ItemQty4.ToString();
txtSalesInvoiceForm_Qty5.Text = (salesInvoice.ItemQty5 == 0) ? string.Empty : salesInvoice.ItemQty5.ToString();
txtSalesInvoiceForm_Unit1.Text = salesInvoice.Unit1;
txtSalesInvoiceForm_Unit2.Text = salesInvoice.Unit2;
txtSalesInvoiceForm_Unit3.Text = salesInvoice.Unit3;
txtSalesInvoiceForm_Unit4.Text = salesInvoice.Unit4;
txtSalesInvoiceForm_Unit5.Text = salesInvoice.Unit5;
txtSalesInvoiceForm_Particulars1.Text = salesInvoice.Particulars1;
txtSalesInvoiceForm_Particulars2.Text = salesInvoice.Particulars2;
txtSalesInvoiceForm_Particulars3.Text = salesInvoice.Particulars3;
txtSalesInvoiceForm_Particulars4.Text = salesInvoice.Particulars4;
txtSalesInvoiceForm_Particulars5.Text = salesInvoice.Particulars5;
```

Is there any way something like this?

```
int index = 1;
foreach (SalesInvoiceItem item in salesInvoice.SalesInvoiceItems)
{
    (txtSalesInvoiceForm_Qty + index.ToString()).Text = Value;
    indexer++                        
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Control parent = this.pnlParent; // this must be the immediate parent control

int index = 1;
foreach (SalesInvoiceItem item in salesInvoice.SalesInvoiceItems)
{
    TextBox tb = parent.FindControl( "txtSalesInvoiceForm_Qty" + index++ ) as TextBox;
    tb.Text = Value;       
}
```

The key is `FindControl()`, which searches the immediate children of a parent. Personally I think this is sloppy code in most cases.

Comment: thanks! this's exactly what i wanted! Bu how come i can't use parent.FindControl() ? it says Windows.Form.Controls does not contain a definition of FindControl().

Comment: @SiHyungLee - I didn't know you were using Windows Forms (assumed web forms). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.100).aspx for similar functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Use an array rather than so many named variables and just index into the array.